# Possible bug: stroke-linecap="round" get distorted in Firefox while animated

Tags: css, animation, svg

I was answering a question on Stack Overflow when I realised that it may be a bug in Firefox while animating a line with `stroke-linecap="round"`with a  `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

```css
svg{border:1px solid}


path{
  animation: draw 1s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from{transform:scale(0.1,1)}
  to {transform:scale(1,1)}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 100"> 
<path d="M0,50H500" stroke="blue" stroke-width = "25" stroke-linecap="round" transform="scale(0.1,1)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

This is the end result in Chrome:

[image]

And this is in Firefox:

[image]

Please note that this is not happening if the path is not animated.

How can I avoid this problem?

#### UPDATE

Furthermore: tweaking the code I've come up with this:
If I change the `transform="scale(.1,1)"` to `transform="scale(1,1)"` the aspect of the "roundcapness" looks OK at the end of the animation, however the roundness **begins flat** and bump up during the animation as you may see un the next example:

[image]

```css
svg{border:1px solid}


path{
  animation: draw 10s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from{transform:scale(0.1,1)}
  to {transform:scale(1,1)}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 100"> 
<path d="M0,50H500" stroke="blue" stroke-width = "25" stroke-linecap="round" transform="scale(1,1)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess you need it to be with SVG and no pure CSS?

Comment: Report Firefox SVG bugs [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after removing the `transform` attribute of the path. Now it works correctly on Firefox.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}

path{
  animation: draw 1s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from{transform:scale(0.1,1)}
  to {transform:scale(1,1)}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 100"> 
<path d="M0,50H500" stroke="blue" stroke-width = "25" stroke-linecap="round" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```